# Magento new custom order line "qty" field

Tags: magento

Magento currently has the following standard "qty" fields; for each order lines (for example):

```
[qty_canceled] => 0.0000
[qty_invoiced] => 1.0000
[qty_ordered] => 1.0000
[qty_refunded] => 0.0000
[qty_shipped] => 1.0000
```

On the order view, you can see it like this:

[image]
What I'd like to do is add a new custom field called **qty_allocated**

This new field is going to be used with a 3rd party integration for automated order processing and I don't want to use the official qty fields.

Does anyone know if this is possible? If so, how can I go about achieving this?
I need to be able to display/update this field also on Magento.

Thanks in advance for any tips/guides.

Comment: Thats quite a loaded question. It's simple to add a new field for this, but creating the backend etc is maybe a bit much to post as an answer!

Comment: I can take care of the backend. Can you give me any hint on how to get the field created? That is my starting point.

Comment: Do you need to attribute to be on the product, or on the order item itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Example creating an attrtibute for an order item:

```
$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup('core_setup');

$installer ->addAttribute('order_item', 'qty_allocated', array(
    'label'     => 'QTY Allocated',
    'type'      => 'varchar',
    'input'     => 'text',
    'visible'   => true,
    'required'  => false,
    'position'  => 10,
));
//$installer->endSetup();
```